# Hice este programa que debería pedir un numero, luego pedir una opción pero no me pide nada

Tags: c

Que debería hacer: el programa debería pedirme un numero, luego pedirme una opción(s para sumar, r para restar, m para multiplicar o d para dividir) y cuando yo elija una opción me pedirá el otro valor con el cual se hará la operación

El problema es que funciona bien hasta donde me pide el primer valor pero no me pide elegir una opción y como no me pide elegir opción, tampoco me pide que ingrese el otro valor para hacer la operación

Me salte algún paso? hice algo mal? No pido que me hagan el programa, solo que me señalen mi error por favor

Aqui el programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int a, b, suma;
    char salir_continuar, caracter;
    float resultado;
    int valor_acumulado= 0;

do
    {

    printf("Introduzca un valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

     printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
          scanf("%c", &caracter);

          switch(caracter){

             case ('s'):
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                valor_acumulado= valor_acumulado+ a+b;
                printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a+b, valor_acumulado, resultado);
                break;

             case ('r'):
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                valor_acumulado= valor_acumulado+ a-b;
                printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a-b, valor_acumulado, resultado);
                break;

            case ('m'):
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                valor_acumulado= valor_acumulado+ a*b;
                printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d", a*b, valor_acumulado, resultado);
                break;

            case ('d'):
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                valor_acumulado= valor_acumulado+ a/b;
                printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",a/b, valor_acumulado, resultado);
                break;

            case ('x'):
                printf("El valor acumulado de las operaciones es %d", valor_acumulado);
                resultado=  valor_acumulado;
                break;

    default: ;

}

     printf("\n\n%c quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...", 168);
     printf("\n\n elija n para salir o s para continuar: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &salir_continuar);

    system("cls");

    }while(salir_continuar!='n');

   printf("\n Hasta luego");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Como en tantas otras líneas de código... tienes esta expresión `printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a+b, valor_acumulado, resultado);`. ¿Qué pretendes mostrar? Estás poniendo una referencia a dato entero con `%d` pero le indicas 3 variables distintas. O usas `a+b`, o `valor_acumulado` o `resultado`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el segundo scanf, que reconoce el salto de línea del primer scanf y realiza un comportamiento extraño. Añade un espacio en blanco delante de "%c" así  " %c":

```
printf("Introduzca un valor: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
scanf(" %c", &caracter);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!